# Correctly building up a list in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm attempting to write a predicate to remove elements from an ordered list in Prolog. This is part of a homework assignment and I'm very confused about how Prolog's semantics work in general.

When I try the following function with the goal `rdup([1,2], L).` I get `false`. I've traced the goal and it looks like I'm not supposed to be building up the result list the way I am building it up with recursive calls to rdup. I'm not certain how I should be building up the result list. Here's the function:

```
rdup([],M).
rdup([X],[X]).
rdup([H1,H2|T], M) :- H1 \= H2, rdup(T, [M,H1,H2]).
rdup([H1,_|T], M) :- rdup(T, [M,H1]).
```

Can anyone tell me where my reasoning is wrong or how one is supposed to build up a list recursively in Prolog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it's **not** functions.
It's predicates, they only say, what's true, what's not, and under what conditions.

Here are your program:

```
rdup([],[]).
rdup([X],[X]).
rdup([H,H|T], M) :- rdup([H|T], M).
rdup([H1,H2|T], [H1|M]) :- H1 \= H2, rdup([H2|T], M).
```

Now a little bit of explanation.

Firstly, what says "rdup(X,Y)"? It's not saying "Take ordered list in X, and put list X without duplicates in Y", but it says "This fact will be true, if Y is an list X without duplicates, in assumption that X is an ordered list". Notice, that we don't talk about "returning values" or sth like that.

First line says, that the empty list is a list without duplicates of empty list. Quite obvious, right?

Next line is basically the same, but with one element.

Third line says, that if we have list, which consists from two same elements H and tail T, then the ordered list of this list ([H,H|T]) is the same, as it would be with only one element H. That's why we have "M" in both predicates unmodified.

I hope you will analyse the last predicate on your own, Prolog is not as hard as it looks to be. Good luck!

Comment: If you use `dif/2` instead of `(\=)/2`, you get a more generally usable program that can also be used to correctly anwser queries like `?- rdup([X,Y,Z], Ls).`.